# How to build a heap better than Incremental and In-place method using decision tree?

Tags: binary-trees, heaps, heap-sort

For an array A = [a1, a2, a3, a4] of distinct numbers, I have built heap using binary decision tree by Incremental and In-place method.

Incremental method:
[image]

In-place method:
[image]

**Is there a way to build heap using decision tree for inputs of size 4 that uses fewer decisions in the worst-case, compared to above methods?**

Notes on heap: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6GDPYLwp2cY3lfbEVWNHlrSlE
Incremental method - page 36, In-place method - page 48.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Every branch in above methods makes a comparison to built a heap.
So, is there any other algo. that makes fewer comparison to built a heap?

Comment: When $a_1$ and $a_3$ are less-than $a_2$ and $a_4$, your upper decision tree won't compare $a_1$ to $a_3$, so are your leaves just a _rough idea_ of the heap? ​ ​